# Sum of per day sale in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in sql server something like this

```
userid username sale date 
 1       azad    50  12/07/2013 
 2       akash   40  12/07/2013
 3       sushil  30  12/07/2013
 4       pankaj  20  12/07/2013
 5       akash   40  12/07/2013
 6       sushil  30  12/07/2013
 9       pankaj  20  12/07/2013
```

Now i want the sum of sale date of all the user but from the last sale all the  user did I want output like this

```
ClosingBalance

140
```

this result based on the last entry of all the four users

Comment: can you provide a sample output?

Comment: how you define the last entry, since only date is there? what happens if two sales is there in same day ?

Comment: @Nithesh check what result i want

Comment: see that is just for example means i need data from  last entry of every user @Nithesh

Comment: Where is **140** coming from?

Comment: if that sales date contain time also we can identify the last entry. otherwise how can we identify the last entry??

Comment: its the sum of last four entries of azad,sushil,akash,pankaj it was just for example @Nithesh

Comment: @AzadChouhan Does the table contains any auto incremented primary key value?

Comment: The column `userid` seems somewhat confusingly named. It looks like a `balanceid` rather than having a one to one relationship to particular  usernames.

Comment: yes there is a column but i did not mentioned that here can i have to mention that also???? @Nithesh

Comment: @AzadChouhan - So potentially you can use that as the tiebreaker then. It's not ideal as identity values can be inserted out of order with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`. I'd rather store the full `datetime`

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC) AS RN
FROM  Balances
)
SELECT SUM(sale)
FROM T
WHERE RN=1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f1e9/2)

Comment: what happens if two entry is there in same date?

Comment: @Nithesh - Then in the absence of a tie breaker it will use either one of them. The sample schema has no suitable tie breaker. Presumably `username,date` is unique.

Comment: I think he wants the latest entry, then [date] must contain time also. This will work fine on that case.

Comment: yes u r right @Nithesh I need the sum from latest entries from all the users

Comment: @AzadChouhan - So can a `username` have more than one entry on a given date or not? If it can you need to have some other column that differentiates the latest one. e.g. `ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC` or store the `datetime` not just the date.

Comment: yes user can have more than one entry and i have to get latest sale record and have to do sum of all that users @MartinSmith

Answer (score -1):

```
$sum_sale= mysql_query('SELECT sum(sale) FROM `TABLE` AND '2011-12-09' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate;');
$sum_sales_total = mysql_fetch_array($sum_sales);
```

This should help you on your way.